# PHP datetime difficulty

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

It's one of essential things but I'm tired of configuring php, mysql datetime on each server. What I need is standalone (application based) solution for my every php project that will get correct datetime (maybe from authoritive time server) based on timezone or city. I need some class or function which works like `gettimefor("Baku")` and it gets correct timestamp value.

Any solutions? I'm really confused.

Comment: you could use date_timezone_set function in your code. Then It wont change according to the position of server

Comment: you can take a look at [Zend date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.html). It can be used with any project without the entire zend framework.

Comment: Do you want to customize timezones based on where your visitors are located?, localize datetimes?

Comment: Guys I need to set 1 fixed timezone for whole project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one fixed time zone per project then do:

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```

Somewhere in index.php or whatever is executed first.

Edit:

List of supported time zones:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Look it's correct result that returns me http://writecodeonline.com/php/ : http://joxi.ru/OR4sU_3JTJAjdLBiCmU But on my own server this doesn't return correct result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default timezone to the user's local timezone, you have to combine PHP and JavaScript. Here's how to do it: (found here: https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['timezone']))
{
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['offset']))
    {
    ?>
    <script>
    var d = new Date()
    var offset= -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    location.href = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?offset="+offset;
    </script>
    <?php    
    }
    else
    {
        $zonelist = array('Kwajalein' => -12.00, 'Pacific/Midway' => -11.00, 'Pacific/Honolulu' => -10.00, 'America/Anchorage' => -9.00, 'America/Los_Angeles' => -8.00, 'America/Denver' => -7.00, 'America/Tegucigalpa' => -6.00, 'America/New_York' => -5.00, 'America/Caracas' => -4.30, 'America/Halifax' => -4.00, 'America/St_Johns' => -3.30, 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' => -3.00, 'America/Sao_Paulo' => -3.00, 'Atlantic/South_Georgia' => -2.00, 'Atlantic/Azores' => -1.00, 'Europe/Dublin' => 0, 'Europe/Belgrade' => 1.00, 'Europe/Minsk' => 2.00, 'Asia/Kuwait' => 3.00, 'Asia/Tehran' => 3.30, 'Asia/Muscat' => 4.00, 'Asia/Yekaterinburg' => 5.00, 'Asia/Kolkata' => 5.30, 'Asia/Katmandu' => 5.45, 'Asia/Dhaka' => 6.00, 'Asia/Rangoon' => 6.30, 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' => 7.00, 'Asia/Brunei' => 8.00, 'Asia/Seoul' => 9.00, 'Australia/Darwin' => 9.30, 'Australia/Canberra' => 10.00, 'Asia/Magadan' => 11.00, 'Pacific/Fiji' => 12.00, 'Pacific/Tongatapu' => 13.00);
        $index = array_keys($zonelist, $_REQUEST['offset']);
        $_SESSION['timezone'] = $index[0];
    }
}
date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone']);

//rest of your code goes here
?>
```